# Printing arrays are not working in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am kind of new in shell scripting and trying to learn arrays. I declared array value but when I am trying to print that array it is giving me an error(bad substitution).
I am pasting the code below, please suggest to me what is wrong here-

```
➜  ~ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

array=['foo','bar','a','b']
echo 1
echo "${array[0]}"
➜  ~ sh test.sh
1
test.sh: 5: Bad substitution
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: declare array using '()' **array=('foo' 'bar')**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the system you're using `sh` might be not be Bash and
it's not Bash on yours, it can be dash for example. Run your script with Bash:

```
$ bash arr.sh
1
[foo,bar,a,b]
```

Or set an executable bit and call the script without providing the name of the interpreter since you already have the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)):

```
$ chmod +x test.sh
$ ./test.sh
1
[foo,bar,a,b]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was a very silly mistake from my side. I am using zsh.

Comment: You might use zsh as the default _interactive_ shell but the `Bad substitution` message does not come from it, check `zsh test.sh`.

Comment: Post output of `ls -Al /bin/sh` to find out what's the `sh` mapped to on your system.

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Aug 20  2021 /bin/sh -> dash

Comment: So it's dash. You'd get the same error if you called test.sh with dash: `dash test.sh`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out,  it was a good learning today. All thanks to you